# Google OAuth Access Token expired how to get Refresh Token

Tags: android, google-oauth, drive

I am working on Google Drive Rest Api to upload and download file to google drive after sign in with google.

I am able to get the access token which is expired after every 60mintes i want to get refresh access token with sign in using previous token how can i achive this .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the refresh token provided when the user login and send POST request using this url

> https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?client_id=**your_client_id**&client_secret=**your_client_secret**&refresh_token=**refresh_token**&grant_type=**refresh_token**
>
> for more information check out documentation:
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#handlingresponse